# access a ascx parameter in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I was wondering if I could add a user control to a page with a parameter and then access that parameter in the code behiind for initiallization.

For example on my aspx page i would have somethign like.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="myMap" Src="~/Map.ascx" %>
blah 
blah 
blah
<uc1:myMap ID="myMap1" runat="server" DefaultCountry="UnitedStates"/>
```

How would I access the DefaultCountry parameter in my Map.ascx.cs code behind file.

If I am off base on this what is the correct implementation?

EDIT:

Figured it out

in .aspx page

```
<uc1:myPartnerMap ID="MyPartnerMap1" runat="server" defaultCountry="USA"/>
```

in .ascx.cs of the user control

```
private string defaultCountry;   

    public String DefaultCountry
    {
        get { return defaultCountry; }
        set { defaultCountry = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            CountrySelector.SelectedValue = defaultCountry;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution to the problem!

Comment: +1 for providing the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You would call the usercontrol first, and then the public property on the user control.

```
myMap1.DefaultCountry = "UnitedStates";
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case DefaultCountry sould be a property of your user control. So you can simply access it by using this property of the user control's instance.

Comment: What if I had to use this to set a default on a dropdown such as this, this is different i take it.<asp:DropDownList ID="CountrySelector" runat="server" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="CountrySelector_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />

Answer (score 0):

This code is enough

in .aspx page

```
<uc1:myPartnerMap ID="MyPartnerMap1" runat="server" DefaultCountry ="USA"/>
```

in .ascx.cs of the user control

```
public String DefaultCountry { get; set; }
```

The property will be initialized with the value "USA" automatically.